# Quais as diferenças de implementação entre a console.log do Browser e do Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ontem estava a usar uma classe do MooTools no Node.js e deparei-me com um comportamento estranho no `console.log` do Node.js. O código funciona lindamente, mas a consola não mostra o que eu sei que está lá.

Por exemplo fazendo:

```
function FN(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
FN.prototype.dados = {
    idade: 10,
    nacionalidade: 'pt'
};
var fn = new FN('Sérgio');
console.log(fn);
```

a consola do Node.js dá-me:

```
{nome: "Sérgio"}
```

enquanto que a consola do Browser dá:

```
{nome: "Sérgio", dados: Object}
```

Baralhado com o resultado fiz `console.log(fn.dados);` e aí ambos me mostraram o resultado esperado: `{idade: 10, nacionalidade: "pt"}`.

Daqui deduzo que a consola do Node.js não mostra propriedades adicionadas ao `_prototype_` que não sejam próprias do Objeto. Ou seja, porque `fn.hasOwnProperty('dados')` é `false` então o Node.js não mostra essa propriedade.

Existem mais diferenças entre a implementação da `console.log` do Browser e do Node.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método `console.log` [não é padronizado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log), de modo que cada *browser* pode implementá-lo da maneira que achar melhor. E de fato, executando [seu exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/cmbvy7ya/) em diferentes *browsers*, tive diferentes resultados:

- Firefox: `Object { nome: "Sérgio" }`
- Chrome e Opera: `FN` ou `FN {nome: "Sérgio", dados: Object}` (dependendo de *quando* se abre o console - antes ou depois da página terminar de carregar)
- Safari: `FN`
- Internet Explorer: `[object Object] {dados: Object {...}, nome: "Sérgio"}`

Uma diferença crucial entre o tratamento dado no *browser* e o no node.js é que o primeiro é **interativo** enquanto o segundo é apenas uma saída para o log (seja o *shell* ou algum arquivo). Os *browsers* - todos que testei - permitem que você clique no objeto impresso no log e inspecione sua estrutura<sup>1</sup>, navegando pelos seus diversos campos inclusive seu protótipo. Daí não importa tanto quais informações são exibidas no formato string, pois se você quiser mais informações ou se quiser alguma informação específica é só buscar por ela.

Já o node.js precisa escolher com cuidado o que informar, pois o que aparecer no log é tudo o que o usuário terá acesso, e mais nada. Assumindo-se que um objeto pode fazer parte de uma hierarquia extensa, não faz muito sentido logar todos os seus campos inclusive os herdados, pois isso "poluiria" o log e tornaria mais difícil encontrar a informação relevante. Melhor deixar que o próprio programador escolha o que quer que lhe seja exibido, logando ou o objeto ou algum outro de sua cadeia de protótipos.

Para uma descrição precisa de como o node.js imprime objetos complexos, ver [a documentação do `console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data): ela diz que a primeira string pode conter instruções de formatação<sup>2</sup>, ou então cada argumento é passado para a função [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options). Esta por sua vez possui várias opções, como por exemplo `showHidden` - que *talvez* sirva para mostrar as propriedades do protótipo (essa opção na realidade serve para ver as propriedades não enumeráveis, o que a princípio não tem relação alguma com o protótipo<sup>3</sup>, mas pode ser que ajude - infelizmente não tenho o node.js aqui para testar).

---

<sub>1. Cabe notar que nem sempre a estrutura inspecionada é do objeto tal como ele estava no momento em que foi logado - muitas vezes ela só mostra o objeto tal como está nesse momento. Por isso, quando essa diferença se mostra importante, é mais garantido logar não o objeto em si mas um `JSON.stringify` dele, ou similar.</sub>

<sub>2. Essas instruções de formatação - também suportadas em vários *browsers*, pelo menos os para *desktop* - lembram muito o `printf` do C. Exemplo: `console.log("Hello, %s. You've called me %d times.", "Bob", i+1);`</sub>

<sub>3. A menos que não ser enumerável seja o que está impedindo o protótipo de aparecer... Sinceramente não sei, as informações sobre o assunto me parecem um tanto escassas.</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! De facto a comparação entre _interativo_ e _log_ faz sentido. Usando `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obkject));` é útil para criar um clone do que se passou naquele momento do script. Obrigado de novo: `+1`

Comment: @Sergio Nunca tinha pensado nisso! Nossa, vai me ajudar bastante nos *debugs* futuros...